# Отступ при клике на якорь

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать сверху отступ при клике на якорь меню. Сейчас у меня при клике проматывается к блоку и часть заголовка перекрывается. Как сделать отступ сверху 50px

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top-50
Поиграйте со значением

Comment: Отлично. А теперь появилась проблемка, скролл доходит до элемента и потом вверх на 50px. Как сделать так чтобы была единая анимация, учитывая отступ в 50px ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top - 50;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Отлично. А теперь появилась проблемка, скролл доходит до элемента и потом вверх на 50px. Как сделать так чтобы была единая анимация, учитывая отступ в 50px

Comment: Не может такого быть.

Comment: У меня все ок, скиньте весь код по данной задаче.